# How to mirror/synchronize a local workspace folder with the server folder?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tfvc

I have a folder that regularly gets updated. This folder is a part of a TFS workspace. I need to commit all those changes to the workspace once they occur (add what isn't there, delete what was removed and update what was changed).

Currently, I have a script that runs `tf vc folderdiff` command on the folder and its server counterpart, parses out the output to get three lists - files that need to be added, deleted and updated. It then manually adds, deletes and updates those files by invoking tf add/delete/checkout on batches of files (trying to add/delete/checkout in one go can cause an error if there are too many files in the list).

There has to be some better way. Is there some kind of tf command where I can tell it, look at this local folder, look at the server folder that is mapped to it and make the server folder look exactly the same? Bonus points if I can specify some kind of filter to exclude certain paths or file names/extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there exists a `tf reconcile` command. You can learn more about the syntax here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/reconcile-command

Off the top of my head, the following command should do what I want:

```
tf reconcile [path to folder] /promote /adds /deletes /recursive /noprompt
```

There is also `/exclude` that can be used to filter unwanted files, so I get the bonus points too.

Of course I had to stumble upon it right **after** asking a question...